# How to refer to typedef defined in template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I'm new to C++ templates and I'm heavily struggling with some compiler complaints. I'm defining a class-scope type in a template class and want to refer to this type from somewhere else. I tried different ways to qualify the type's name but the only thing I achieve is getting different error messages.

Here's the definition of my class in `mylist.h`, a classic list implementation:

```
template<typename T> class MyList {

public:
    class ListElement; // forward declaration

    typedef ListElement* LPOS;  // the problematic typedef

    // helper class for list elements
    class ListElement {
        LPOS next;
        int content;

      public:
        ListElement(T);
        LPOS getNext();
        ... 
    };

    // the list itself

    MyList();
    ListElement* first;

    LPOS add(T);
    LPOS insert(T, LPOS);
    ... // more list functions
};
```

Now I want to use the LPOS type from outside in `main.cpp`:

```
include "mylist.h"
...

void testList (void) {

    LPOS pos;                // compiler error: expected ';' before pos
    MyList<T>::LPOS pos; // compiler error: expected initializer before pos
    MyList::LPOS pos;    // compiler error: expected ';' before pos
```

I tried to use "using" but that didn't lead anywhere either. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyList<T>::LPOS pos;`: here `T` has no meaning. You need to instantiate `MyList` with a real type:

`MyList<double>::LPOS pos;` should work correctly.

`double` is an example here: you need to change `T` to the type you need.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. @Daniel Frey, you're right, I must use the correct generic type, i.e. the same as for the list I'm using it with. Otherwise the compiler produces an error that it cannot convert the types, e.g. `MyList<int>::LPOS` and `MyList<double>::LPOS`.

Answer (score 0):

You need some concrete type, e.g. `MyList<int>::LPOS` as `T` is not valid in `testList`. The problem is that you need the correct template parameter, as `MyList<int>::LPOS` is not the same as `MyList<double>::LPOS`. Find out what you need and use the correct one.